# how to install in MinGW using msys 1.0 new packages?

Tags: mingw, msys, msys2

I know Msys2 has pacman for installing/updating packages
How do I do the same in Msys 1.0?

I need to use Msys 1.0 because Msys2 is not supported in Windows 7 64 bit ultimate that well gets Cygwin7 dll replacement mismatch errors, I need to install lets say python on msys 1.0 how would I do it?

```
2 [main] pacman (21968) C:\msys64\usr\bin\pacman.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x180326400/0x180327400.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
35147604 [main] pacman 10420 fork: child -1 - forked process 21968 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000005, errno 11
```

in Msys2 I would do

```
pacman --noconfirm -Suy python2 make pkg-config mingw-w64-x86_64-glib2 mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain
```

to get packages

```
python2 
make 
pkg-config 
mingw-w64-x86_64-glib2 
mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain
```

**Edit:**

Looks like 
MinGW Installallation Manager is the only way to go, it's even nicer due to it having a GUI

All I need to do I guess is pick from the 
MSYS -> MSYS System Builder tab 
That's all it has

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay Found the actual problem how to fix the cygwin1.dll mismatch issue.
Don't load the msys2 console shell after it finishes installing.

Instead open command prompt from your windows system and use it like so

```
C:\msys64\usr\bin\bash -lc "pacman --noconfirm -Suy python2 make pkg-config mingw-w64-x86_64-glib2 mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain"
```

Output looks like so

```
:: Starting full system upgrade...
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (20) make-4.1-4  mingw-w64-x86_64-binutils-2.26-21
              mingw-w64-x86_64-crt-git-5.0.0.4627.03684c4-1
              mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-5.3.0-2  mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-ada-5.3.0-2
              mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-fortran-5.3.0-2
              mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libgfortran-5.3.0-2
              mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs-5.3.0-2
              mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-objc-5.3.0-2  mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb-7.11-1
              mingw-w64-x86_64-glib2-2.46.2-3
              mingw-w64-x86_64-headers-git-5.0.0.4627.53be55d-1
              mingw-w64-x86_64-libmangle-git-5.0.0.4509.2e5a9a2-1
              mingw-w64-x86_64-libwinpthread-git-5.0.0.4573.628fdbf-1
              mingw-w64-x86_64-make-4.1.2351.a80a8b8-1
              mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config-0.29.1-1
              mingw-w64-x86_64-tools-git-5.0.0.4592.90b8472-1
              mingw-w64-x86_64-winpthreads-git-5.0.0.4573.628fdbf-1
              pkg-config-0.28-2  python2-2.7.11-1

Total Installed Size:  591.03 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:        0.00 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
(20/20) checking keys in keyring                   [#####################] 100%
(20/20) checking package integrity                 [#####################] 100%
(20/20) loading package files                      [#####################] 100%
(20/20) checking for file conflicts                [#####################] 100%
(20/20) checking available disk space              [#####################] 100%
:: Processing package changes...
( 1/20) reinstalling python2                       [#####################] 100%
( 2/20) reinstalling make                          [#####################] 100%
( 3/20) reinstalling pkg-config                    [#####################] 100%
( 4/20) reinstalling mingw-w64-x86_64-libwinpt...  [#####################] 100%
( 5/20) reinstalling mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs     [#####################] 100%
( 6/20) reinstalling mingw-w64-x86_64-glib2        [#####################] 100%
No schema files found: doing nothing.
( 7/20) reinstalling mingw-w64-x86_64-binutils     [#####################] 100%
( 8/20) reinstalling mingw-w64-x86_64-headers-git  [#####################] 100%
( 9/20) reinstalling mingw-w64-x86_64-crt-git      [#####################] 100%
(10/20) reinstalling mingw-w64-x86_64-winpthre...  [#####################] 100%
(11/20) reinstalling mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc          [#####################] 100%
(12/20) reinstalling mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-ada      [#####################] 100%
(13/20) reinstalling mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libg...  [#####################] 100%
(14/20) reinstalling mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-fortran  [#####################] 100%
(15/20) reinstalling mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-objc     [#####################] 100%
(16/20) reinstalling mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb          [#####################] 100%
(17/20) reinstalling mingw-w64-x86_64-libmangl...  [#####################] 100%
(18/20) reinstalling mingw-w64-x86_64-make         [#####################] 100%
(19/20) reinstalling mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config   [#####################] 100%
(20/20) reinstalling mingw-w64-x86_64-tools-git    [#####################] 100%
```

To use it you must set the PATHS accordingly not only for windows PATH but also for bash path with /c/ meaning C: drive etc..

```
SET PATH=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;C:\msys64\usr\bin;C:\Python27;%PATH%
echo %PATH%
sh.exe -c "export PATH=/c/msys64/mingw64/bin:/c/msys64/usr/bin:${PATH} ; gcc -v"
```

Comment: I had the "cygheap base mismatch detected" problem with "mkdir" compiling c++ with netbeans with mingw. I'd missed "C:\msys64\usr\bin" from my PATH which, I guess, meant it was looking for "mkdir" in the cygwin64 folder. Correcting the path resolved the issue. Thx.